# Select from a created view in SQL with specific conditions

Tags: sql, view

[database uml]

[image: 1]

I'm trying to create a view with all movies that are ranked better than average (MOVIEID, TITLE, YEAR and RANK as columns).

I have two questions regarding this:

(1) Is the code displayed below the optimal solution?:

```
    CONNECT TO dbp122;

    CREATE VIEW dbp122.avgRatedMovies AS
    SELECT movies.movieid, movies.title, movies.year, rankings.rank
    FROM movies 
    LEFT JOIN rankings 
      ON movies.movieid = rankings.movieid
    WHERE rankings.rank > (SELECT AVG(rank) FROM rankings);

    DISCONNECT dbp122;
```

(2) I'm now trying to select from that view for all years the single movie with the highest ranking
(if more than one movie has the highest ranking for a year it should be in an additional row; YEAR, TITLE and RANK as columns). How could this be done?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: One question per question.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing `LEFT JOIN`? anyway, your query finally doing `INNER JOIN` as you have used the left joined table's condition in `WHERE` clause.

You can use `avg` analytical function and `INNER JOIN` as follows:

```
Select * from
(SELECT movies.movieid, 
        movies.title, 
        movies.year,
        rankings.rank,
        Avg(rankings.rank) over() avg_rank
   FROM movies 
   JOIN rankings ON movies.movieid = rankings.movieid) t
Where rank >= avg_rank;
```